# Formating timestams on x axis using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to format timestamps on x axis as `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"`. `ts` is list of timestamps and how to show on x axis values:

"2018-5-23 14:00", "2018-5-23 14:15" and "2018-5-23 14:30".

My current chart shows:

23 14:00, 23 14:05, 23 14:10, 23 14:15, 23 14:20, 23 14:25, 23 14:30.

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('fivethirtyeight')

ts = [datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 23, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 23, 14, 15), datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 23, 14, 30)]
values =[3, 7, 6]
plt.plot(ts, values, 'o-')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to set your x ticks so that only the values you want will be displayed. This can be done using `plt.xticks(tick_locations, tick_labels)`.

To get the dates in the right format you need to specify a `DateFormatter` and apply it to your x axis.

Your code would look like:

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
style.use('fivethirtyeight')

ts = [datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 23, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 23, 14, 15), datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 23, 14, 30)]

values =[3, 7, 6]
plt.plot(ts, values, 'o-')
plt.xticks(ts, ts)  # set the x ticks to your dates

date_formatter = DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")  # choose desired date format
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_formatter)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @LiverpoolBitlas no problem :). On SO, if an answer was helpful, you can upvoted/accept an answer if you wish as described here - [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)